# Rails: getting the 'new' path for a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url

I have a nested resource which appears like so in my routes:

```
resource :reviews do
  resource :entries
end
```

I'm trying to create a link for a new entry path like so:

```
<%= link_to "New Entry", new_review_entry_path(@review) %>
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error message:

```
undefined method `new_review_entry_path' for #<#<Class:0x5150d78>:0x483c798>
```

I checked rake routes, and it turns out that the route should be pluralized into:

```
new_reviews_entries_path(@review)
```

Unfortunately, when I do that, then I get an odd url:

```
/reviews/entries/new.1
```

Obviously, that doesn't work, either. Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `resources`, not `resource`. Your first try was the right one ;)

```
resources :reviews do
    resources :entries
end
```

You should use `resource` when the resource is "unique". For instance, if a user has one profile, you would do:

```
resources :users do
    resource :profile
end
```